# How to get id of new record which was ignored(replaced) becase of unique fields

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I need to know the ID of newly created record, but this record has unique field:

```
CREATE TABLE materials (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    color_id INTEGER,
    count INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE colors (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

I'm using simple TextBox, to set color, I want it to be inserted and then receive it's id. How can I do this?

Comment: _SELECT last_insert_rowid()_  You should provide your code that inserts the new record to get a more precise answer

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341178/getting-the-last-insert-id-with-sqlite-net-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

For example:
INSERT INTO color(name)
VALUES("blue one")
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

You can keep result in variable and then use in another query. You can also use some ORM and it will handle for you.

Possible duplication of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row).